# How to save XML data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, textbox

In my table there is one XML column. I want to fetch the XML data in one textbox and make some corrections and update it:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     con.Open();
     string str = "select C1 from TableName where C2='" + txt1.Text+ "'";

     SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str, con);
     XmlReader xml = cmd1.ExecuteXmlReader();
     xml.Read();

     txt2.Text = xml.ReadOuterXml();

     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
     doc.LoadXml(txt2.Text);
}
```

Now I want to make some changes and update it in my database. When I try to change in textbox it does not work. How can I make changes and update in database? Please help

Comment: can you please update the question and your xml which you need to update in text box or in db ?.

Comment: when i changed in Textbox and Press Submit Button then Updated in DB

Comment: Yes what is your XML I think there is some problem in your XML format

Comment: @Arun Gairola,there is no problem.can u referme in which way we Updatedin DB

Answer (score 2):

Update Like this

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{ 
command.CommandText = "Update TableName set  C1 =  @C1 where C2 = @C2 ";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C1", Textbox2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C2", Textbox1.text);
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: it shows Error like "Must declare the scalar variable "@C1"."

Comment: Please see the updated one there is some white space problem .

Comment: Your answer is correct, It might be additionally beneficial to check if the xml is valid before updating its value in the database.